# c# release optimization unused string

Tags: c#, release

Simple question :

Is concatenation of the strings A and B not done at all in a release version in VS20XX?

```
string A = // Dynamic string
string B = // Another Dynamic string

DoNothing(A+B);
...
void DoNothing(string MyString)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    // actual code here using MyString
    #endif
}
```

In case it is not clear, i am trying to create some debug probes, but i don't want the concatenations of the messages to affect the performance of the final version...

Comment: Any reason not to add the debug calls within `#ifdef DEBUG`?

Comment: Any variable that's not read from will be optimized out in a release build. You will probably even get a compiler warning.

Comment: I doubt you could get any guarantee that it won't be done.  Since the method body will end up being empty the actual call is likely to be omitted.  Whether the runtime realizes that the string concatenation has no side effects, and can therefore be omitted, is likely something it could *possibly* do but I doubt you could *guarantee* it would do.

Comment: @MotKohn It's not quite that easy.  If, for example, there were any side effects as a result of creating the parameter that the method then never uses, those side effects still need to happen.

Comment: @Servy you are right but in OP question looks like it's all guarded with `#ifdef DEBUG`. Concatenating is not a side effect.

Comment: @MotKohn The `#if` statement is *long* after the parameters need to be evaluated.  And yes, string concatenation doesn't have any side effects, but that doesn't mean that the runtime necessarily does a check to ensure that the computation of the parameters has no side effects, and possibly eludes them, if a method doesn't need it.  I suspect that it would be *allowed* to make that optimization, but I strongly suspect that the language/runtime isn't *required* to make it.

Comment: As an aside, if `DoNothing` had `[Conditional( "DEBUG" )]` it would actually elide not just the call to the method, but the evaluation of its arguments.  Even if such an evaluation would have side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually accomplish this by using `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute`:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional( "Debug" )]
void DoNothing( string myString )
{
    // The #if DEBUG is no longer required in here
}
```

This will actually guarantee that the arguments at the call site are not evaluated.

**However**, if `DoNothing` is being called from a separate assembly (your example leaves off the access modifier so it's not clear what the intended visibility is), the behavior of `DoNothing` depends on the symbols defined in the caller, rather than the symbols defined where `DoNothing` was compiled.  If the method ends up being private or internal, this doesn't matter.